# Angular error in passing data through services

Tags: angular

I am passing data through services . 
data.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class Data {
    private urlHistory: string;

    constructor() {
        this.urlHistory = "";
    }

    public setUrlHistoryObj(val: string): void {
        this.urlHistory = val;
    }

    public getUrlHistoryObj(): string {
        return this.urlHistory;
    }
}
```

login.ts

```
if(this.loginForm.value.email == 'samad' && this.loginForm.value.password == 'admin') {
    console.log(`found corresponding user.`);
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/home', {company_id: '659' , policy: '' }]);
    this.data.setUrlHistoryObj("/movie/searchMovie");

}
```

employe.ts

```
constructor(private api:ApiService,private modalService: NgbModal,private router:Router, public httpClient: HttpClient, public data: Data) {
    this.getClaims();
    this.backUrl = this.data.getUrlHistoryObj();
}
```

Im passing some number through this service but in deal.ts its showing error TypeError: this.data.getUrlHistoryObj is not a function. But its a function in data.ts . Any one know where is the problem?

Comment: Looks like `this.data` is of your `Data` class.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you're importing data from @angular/router (`import { Data } from '@angular/router';`) in `employe.ts` instead of your own `Data`?

Answer (score 0):

Your behaviour subject is private make it public so it is accessible